# How to fix broken sudo config in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, sudo

I made changes with **sudo visudo** on Ubuntu 10.04.
I get error in shell:

**sudo: unknown defaults entry `env_resets'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting the "Root Shell" item in the main menu -- AFAIK it is not dependent from `sudo` -- and edit `/etc/sudoers` with `nano` or your other favourite editor. The `env_resets` token should have been typed `env_reset`.

Comment: $ sudo nano /etc/sudoers 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm, when I broke `sudo` as an experiment, it did not allowed to launch anything...